# Batch - Complication with if statements

Tags: batch-file

I'm making a batch game and I was making the shop. I was making the option 'Buy', and there's my problem.

in this command block:

```
if %ans% == 1 (
if %inv% LEQ %maxinv%-=0.8 (
    set /a inv=%inv%+=0.8
    set deaglespace=1

    if %money% GEQ 800 (
        set /a money=%money%-=800
        set deaglemoney=1

    ) else (goto eamount)
) else ( goto tooinv )

if deaglespace==1 (
    if deaglemoney==1 (
        goto deagleseccbuy
    )
)
)
```

I'm trying to check if you have enough `money` and enough `inventory` space, but it doesn't work... Can't find a way to fix this problem...

Thank you for trying!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many, many problems with your code - in addition to the integers-only issue.

Within a block (a parenthesised series of statements) any variation of `var` is **not** visible until th eblock is exited - and that applies to the entire block from the open-parenthesis on the first line to the matching close on the very last.

There is a way of overcoming this problem - you need to invoke the `delayed expansion` option. This means that you need to include the command

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
```

The question is - where?

Once a `setlocal` is executed, any change to the environment will be temporary - it will be backed out when a matching `endlocal` **or** the program reaches end-of-file. There are ways to overcome even this, but it's far easier to simply invoke `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` at the very start of the program, directly after the `@echo off`.

If you do this, then within a block, `%var%` will appear to contain the variable's value at the start of the outer block (not any inner block in the case of nested blocks) but `!var!` will contain the value as it changes.

Your next problem is such statements as `if deaglespace==1 (`. `deaglespace` will **never** be equal to `1`. `%deaglespace%` *may* be equal to `1` if the variable `deaglespace` has a value `1`. If ou have `delayedexpansion` invoked, `!deaglespace!` may have a value of `1`.

Another problem is that if you use `!deaglespace!` to access the current-value of `deaglespace` then what *might* it contain? Could it be set from some prior operation? Could it have no value at all? If it has no value, `if !deaglespace!==1` will be evaluated as `if ==1` which will yield a syntax error. You should explicitly set your values within your code.

Your variables may have names that are obvious to you, but they mean nothing to me, so the minutae of what you are trying to do escapes me. If you mean that you must have 8 units of space and 800 units of money available then you need to establish your freespace in a temporary variable (**don't** use **temp** or **tmp** - these have special meanings to the command-processor) you could use

```
if "%ans%"=="1" (
 set /a $1=%maxinv%-%inv%
 set /a $2=%money% - 800
)
if "%ans%"=="1" (
 if %$1% lss 0 (echo Insufficient inventory space&goto tooinv)
 if %$2% lss 0 (echo Insufficient money&goto eamount)
 set /a money=$2
 set /a inv+=8
 goto deagleseccbuy
)
```

(I often use `$` as a prefix to temporary variablenames. There are two of them, the same as you used `deaglespace` and `deaglemoney`)

Noting that the `set /a` syntax makes the `%` around the object variablenames optional.

Also : `&` separates commands

And: You don't show how `ans` is set. If it it set using a `set /p` then remember that the user can type anything in response, so it's best to quote both sides and perform a string comparison. Feel free to use your original form if you are sure that `ans` is not empty and that it doesn't contain spaces or other characters with a special meaning to the command-interpreter.

Comment: Damn, I just want to say thanks for helping me and thanks to helping me learn more about batch :D

Answer (score 1):

```
if %ans% == 1 (
if %inv% LEQ %maxinv%-=0.8 (
    set /a inv=%inv%+=0.8
```

`SET /A` works only with interegers so `set /a inv=%inv%+=0.8` will not work.
`if %inv% LEQ %maxinv%-=0.8` this will cause a string comparison.`IF` command does not make calculations so you'll need a second variable:

```
if %ans% == 1 (
set /a temp_var=maxinv-=8
if %inv% LEQ %temp_var% (
    set /a inv=inv+=8
```

Comment: But, do I need to put the /a on the set ?

Comment: `set /a` is how you do math. `set` by itself just assigns values to variables.